# IntelliJ Not Displaying Variable's Property Values in Debugger

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails, groovy, ide

I believe I am responsible for this change in IntelliJ's display, but I do not know what I have done to cause the issue. I have a variable, `data` in my application that when the debugger was stopped at a breakpoint after its assignment, formerly would nicely display all its internal properties and their values, something like this:

```
▼ data
  ▶ propertyOne: Map
  ▶ propertyTwo: Map
```

However, I now see a stackOverflow error while trying to call a `toString` method (not sure why), and instead of data's internal properties, I see methods like `head`, `tail`, `accessOrder`, `table`, see the screenshot:

[image: debugger methods under scope variable]

I believe this *may* have happened when I right-clicked `data` and selected "Inspect". But I'm not certain that is the cause.

### How can I make the variables tab in the debugger show me the selected variable's properties and all of their values?

Edit: Adding screenshot of what happens when one of the nodes is expanded and toString is clicked:

[image]

Comment: What is the declaration of data?

Comment: @NomadMaker it's just like `def data = [ propertyA: getDataA(someConfig), propertyB: getDataB(someOtherConfig) ]`

Comment: Please add the java code for this to the question.

Comment: Those are the internal properties as far the JVM is concerned. You will see the same with `[a: 1].dump()`. Might be easier to just do that toString there, since that will give you   roughly something like the map literlal - or dig into the entrySet

Comment: @cfrick clicking on any of these toStrings, even the dataSet will generate the error `Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.toString()`

Comment: Is there a loop in your map?

Comment: @cfrick there is some circularity I believe, ie some properties reference other properties also contained in `data` if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, that would explain the stack overflow. Yet a naive attempt to make it fail, did not work for me: `[:].tap{ loop = it }` (as in, it does not throw, but just prints the self-reference)

Comment: Correction: this throws with a stack-overflow: `[:].tap{ loop = it }.dump()`

Comment: @cfrick Changing "view as" to "map" or "map.entries" seems to work, but I have to set it each time for tons of nested properties. Do you know of a way I can "reset" or "restore" the "view as" to a default. That seems to be the issue.

Comment: Did it help to reset the Debugger | **Data Views** settings?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Settings (Preferences on macOS) |  | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | **Data Views** settings - if you have [customized them](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/customizing-views.html#renderers). Particularly for **Java** or **Java Type Renderers**.